# Error: Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'

Tags: android

I'm getting Error: Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com' 
Error:Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
[Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

at Android Studio 2.2.1.
Can you help me, please?

Here's my code

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dev.alemappdev.testclevertap"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
compile 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2' // uncomment if using FCM
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```